# Bifurcations in the Duffing oscillator

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm trying to describe all the bifurcations in the two parameter Duffing oscillator:

$$\ddot{x} + ax + bx^3 = 0$$

In phase space with $y = \dot{x}$ I've found the origin to be a centre for $a>0$ and a saddle for $a<0$ and there are two other fixed points $x_1 = (\frac{-a}{b})^{1/2}$ and $x_2 = -(\frac{-a}{b})^{1/2}$ - these exist only when $a,b$ have opposite sign.

I can see that holding $b$ fixed and varying $a$ we have a sort of "pitchfork" bifurcation as the two saddles coalesce at the origin. However can we call this a pitchfork bifurcation given that the stability along the x axis is always marginal and there is no change of stability?

Secondly, I'm not sure if there is a bifurcation if $a$ and $b$ cross the origin together. How can a saddle turn into a centre?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am going to work out the analysis here in the answer, and see if I am able to make sense of your question in the process.

We are given the two parameter oscillator:

$$ \ddot{x} + ax + bx^3 = 0$$

We can rewrite this as follows:

$$ 
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= y \\
\dot{y} & = -ax - b{x^3}
\end{align}
$$

I might refer to $\mathbf{f}(x, y) = (\dot{x}, \dot{y})$ later.

Fixed points occur when nullclines intersect. That is:

$$
\begin{align}
&\quad\; \dot{x} = 0 \wedge \dot{y} = 0 \\
&\equiv y = 0 \wedge 0 = -ax -bx^3 \\
&\equiv y = 0 \wedge 0 = x(-a - bx^2) \\
&\equiv y = 0 \wedge \left(x = 0 \vee x = \pm\sqrt{-a/b}\right) \\
&\equiv (y = 0 \wedge x = 0) \vee \left(y = 0 \wedge x = \sqrt{-a/b}\right) \vee \left(y = 0 \wedge x = -\sqrt{-a/b}\right)
\end{align}
$$

So, there are three fixed points. $\mathbf{p}_1^* = (0, 0)$ is independent of the parameters (i.e. exists for all values of the parameter). The other two ($\mathbf{p}_2^* = (\sqrt{-a/b}, 0)$ and $\mathbf{p}_3^* = (-\sqrt{-a/b}, 0)$) depend on the parameters. In particular, they only exist if $ab < 0$.

We can determine the topological type of hyperbolic fixed points using linear stability analysis. Consider the Jacobian of the problem at hand:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{J}(\mathbf{f}) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \partial\dot{x}/\partial x & \partial\dot{x}/\partial y \\ \partial\dot{y}/\partial x & \partial\dot{y}/\partial y \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -3bx^2 -a & 0 \end{array}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Call the determinant of the Jacobian $\Delta$. Call the trace of the Jacobian $\tau$. We can use $\Delta$ and $\tau$ to figure out the topological type of hyperbolic fixed points.

Let us evalulate the Jacobian at the fixed points. At $\mathbf{p}_1^*$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{J}(\mathbf{f})\mid_{(0, 0)} &= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -a & 0 \end{array}\right] \\
\Delta_1 &= a \\
\tau_1 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

At $\mathbf{p}_2^*$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{J}(\mathbf{f})\mid_{(\sqrt{-a/b}, 0)} &= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 2a & 0 \end{array}\right] \\
\Delta_2 &= -2a \\
\tau_2 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

At $\mathbf{p}_3^*$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{J}(\mathbf{f})\mid_{(-\sqrt{-a/b}, 0)} &= \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 2a & 0 \end{array}\right] \\
\Delta_3 &= -2a \\
\tau_3 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Note that $\Delta_i$ only depend on $a$! When $a < 0$, then we a saddle  one at $\mathbf{p}_1^*$ while $\mathbf{p}_2^*$, $\mathbf{p}_3^*$ are *linear centres* only -- that is, they are non-hyperbolic (the eigenvalues of the Jacobian are pure imaginary), and we cannot say much more about it without further analysis.

The situation is reversed when $a < 0$, with $\mathbf{p}_1^*$ being a non-hyperbolic linear centre, and $\mathbf{p}_2^*, \mathbf{p}_3^*$ being saddles. The fact that things switch from being marginally stable to being linear centres should give us a clue that we might want to test for the existence of [**Hopf Bifurcations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation).

Let's see if there are any conserved quantities in the system that we can make use of in determining the actual stability of the linear centres. A quantity $E(x, y)$ is conserved if $\dot{E} = 0 = \nabla E \cdot \mathbf{f}$:

$$
\begin{align}
&\quad\; \frac{\partial E}{\partial x}y + \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}(-ax - bx^3) = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{\partial E}{\partial x} = (ax + bx^3) \wedge \frac{\partial E}{\partial y} = y
\end{align}
$$

So, you can do partial integration and stuff (I am getting lazy, and will update my post later properly) and we should find that:
$$E(x, y) = \frac{ax^2}{2} + \frac{bx^4}{4} + \frac{y^2}{2},$$

is a conserved quantity. This implies that trajectories of the phase point always lie on level sets of $E$. Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+1%2F2+%28+-x%5E2%29%2B1%2F4+%28+x%5E4%29%2By%5E2%2F2) with $a = -1$ and $b = 1$, we can see that there are clearly closed orbits around the minima of the conserved quantity (which correspond to the fixed points of $\mathbf{f}$):

[image]
[image]

Now when $a = 1$ and $b = -1$ we see:

[image]
[image]

So the origin flipped from being a saddle point, to a centre with orbits around it (as you can see from the contour map!).

When $a = -1 < 0$ and $b = -1 < 0$ we see:

[image]
[image]

When $a = 1 > 0$ and $b = 1 > 0$ we see:

[image]
[image]

So, we go from having marginal stability to oscillations.

The comments bear witness to our confusion regarding whether these are simply degenerate Hopf bifurcations, or whether the pitchfork-like nature of the bifurcations has some signficance worth a name. Ultimately, I had to ask my instructor since I was unable to find a good answer on my own. I quote him here:

> The equation is conservative, or Hamiltonian.  There is a theory of
>   bifurcations for Hamiltonian systems, different from the "generic"
>   bifurcation theory because of the additional structure.  What the
>   Duffing oscillator is experiencing is usually called a "Hamiltonian
>   pitchfork" bifurcation (fix $b$, vary $a$ through $0$).  See p.399 of:
>   http://people.mbi.ohio-state.edu/golubitsky.4/reprintweb-0.5/output/papers/hamiltonian_87.pdf
>   for example.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer! So are these Hopf bifurcations occurring as we vary $a$ and $b$ together? It seems something special happens if we vary $a$ and $b$ whilst keeping them the same sign

Comment: @Wooster That's right. I added a picture for that case since I missed it the first time around. We go from having a saddle point at the origin, to having a centre at the origin.

Comment: Also for a Hopf bifurcation do we not need to see stable spirals turn into unstable spirals surrounded by limit cycles?

Comment: @Wooster Yeah, I was a little unsure about that myself, but seeing the definition here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation#Definition_of_a_Hopf_bifurcation, well, that definitely matches our case. We see closed orbits appear (although not limit cycles), even though its not a limit cycle around a stable/unstable spiral.

Comment: @Wooster You might also be seeing a type of "global bifurcation" maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory#Local_bifurcations?

Comment: Is this holding $b$ fixed and varying $a$? I also thought perhaps there was a global bifurcation as well - I think it's called a homoclinic bifurcation possibly

Comment: @Wooster See in particular: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_sky_catastrophe

Comment: @Wooster You're right, it could also be a homoclinic bifurcation. I am not sure anymore!

Comment: @Wooster In my textbook (by Strogatz, see question 8.2.11), the type of bifurcation in the Duffing Oscillator is not Hopf, but "Degenerate (version of) Hopf bifurcation".

Comment: Ah okay I see. Would you call it a pitchfork bifurcation as we hold b fixed and vary a? As the saddles/centres appear?

Comment: @Wooster It sort of looks like one, right? I think the terminology in the field itself is confused, because I do see some people referring to things like "Hopf-Pitchfork" (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077912001130). I personally would call it a "pitchfork-like degenerate Hopf bifurcation" (http://iopscience.iop.org/0951-7715/12/4/324/pdf/no9424.pdf).

Comment: Yes it is a bit confusing! Looking at 8.2.11 in Strogatz - this seems like it may be a bit different because that is a damped Duffing oscillator?

Comment: @Wooster I ended up asking my instructor about this, because you made some very good points. I have added a little bit to my answer at the end, where I quote him.

Comment: That's really helpful - a good reference! I'm glad that the question was useful for you as well

Comment: @Wooster Thanks to you too for not simply taking my initial answers at face value :)

Comment: @user89 -- I think you miscalculated $\Delta_2$ . For both $p_2^*$ and $p_3^*$ , we have $x^2 = -a/b$ , so the Jacobian has $-3bx^2-a = -3b(-a/b)-a = {^+}3a-a = 2a$ . Then $\Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = -2a$ .

Comment: @mr_e_man you're right!